# How do I use the lteRMCDL tool?

Tags: matlab

I'm following [an example from MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/lte/examples/pdsch-2x2-spatial-multiplexing-throughput-conformance-test.html).

When I run the code I get an erroneous output

```
Error in Untitled3 (line 38)
rmc = lteRMCDL(enb, ncw);
```

Comment: I think there is more to that error.

Answer (score 0):

If the error you describe was preceded by:

> Undefined function 'lteRMCDL' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Then the most likely reason is that you do not have the LTE system toolbox, or that you have an older version which does not contain that function.

You can check which version of MATLAB you are running, and all the installed toolboxes you have along with their version number, by typing `ver` at the command line.  Alternatively , you can check the location of a given function on the path by typing `which lteRMCDL` (this can help if the problem is that you have written a function with the same name as an existing MATLAB function, or if your MATLAB path is not set up correctly).

MATLAB online help shows by default the latest (2013b at time of writing) help and requires you to log in to show archived help files.